# How To achieve transperent background view when Spinner's dropdown menu open

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

As shown in image i want to achieve the transperent view as background when spinner clicked ( image 1).and back to normal view when item selected (image 2)

I have tried following ways, but dint worked.
Any one  have any idea!! .. Any help will be appereciated. Thanks

```
spinnerrelevence.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    //first way
                    mRoot.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transperent));

                    //second way                   
                    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

                    //third way
                    getApplication().setTheme(R.style.Theme_Transparent);


                    //fourth way
                    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transperent);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

In style.xml:

```
<!--for transperent activity-->
<style name="Theme.Transperent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

[image]

[image]).

Comment: Better replace spinner with Android's PopupWindow and use transparent background for the popup layout.

Answer (score 1):

you can use your root layout to set transparency ,like if you have linear layout as a root layout of that screen then **set alpha(51)** for achieve transparency on click of spinner items  and remove alpha on select of spinner items .

or you can use below code to dim background

```
  WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) container.getLayoutParams();
        p.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        p.dimAmount = 0.3f;
        wm.updateViewLayout(container, p);
```

replace container with your view .

Comment: Not exactly as setalpha stay as it is when NO item selected. still it gave me the half solution +1 for that .. thank you.

Comment: Thanks when no item selected you can use setalpha on root layout while clicking on spinner it will work ,let me know if you are facing some problem on this approach.

Comment: it is not working when nothing is selected from spinner item. the view should changed from transperent to normal but it is only working when any item selected.

Comment: you should use setAlpha(1f) on spinner item click for changing view from transparent to normal .can you paste your code where you are using set alpha ?

Comment: not working with coordinatelayout.. anyway thankx for your efforts and help

Answer (score 0):

Here is trick and You can do this to achieve what u want 
As you can spinner in Alert dialog and do like this, which will create the transparent background as u require

```
 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                // create alert dialog
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                final Spinner mSpinner= (Spinner) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);


                // reference UI elements from my_dialog_layout in similar fashion

                mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemClicked());

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

**my_dialog_layout** is the popup layout which you contains the Spinner mySpinner

```
public class OnSpinnerItemClicked implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Clicked : " +
                    parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
```

Comment: it will give me spinner in the dialog but i want spinner item . so i dnt have to click it again for viewing item.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spinner's display style will be in form of dropdown menu. We can also show the spinner in a dialog form.
If you open this in the form of dialog you can achieve what you want.

Just add this in you spinner xml

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

Hope this will help you.